# Does Hadoop only run on (Ubuntu) Linux server OS or I can run it on desktop?

Tags: hadoop

Does Hadoop only run on (Ubuntu) Linux server OS or I can run it on desktop? Sorry for this silly question but I am a little confused about it. As I am trying to run Hadoop on my system and I don't want to use Cloudera or MapR versions of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it on your desktop if you want, people do this all the time with server software, though for testing/production needs you'll probably want to run it on a real server or cloud instance.

Comment: also is latest ubuntu version stable with hadoop.